# Most efficient way to rewrite a html page to a string (MVC 3)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to have this html page rewriting as a string:

```
 <h1>Report @ViewData["reviewId"]</h1>
 <table width="1000">
 @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.Parent_Group_Name))
 {
 <tr bgcolor="gray">
    <td><b>@group.Key</b></td>
 </tr>
     foreach (var line in group)
     { 
      <tr>
          <td><b>@line.Child_Group_Name </b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td width="100%"><b>Question:</b> @String.Format("{0}. {1}",line.Question_Order,line.Question_Label)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td width="100%"><b>Answer:</b> @line.Question_Answer</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
       <td valign=right>
            <table width="100%" >
                <thead bgcolor="BDBDBD">Comments</thead>
                @foreach (var comment in line.Comments)
                { 
                  <tr>
                      <td width="100%"><font size="3" color=302F2F>@comment.Comment_Text</font></td>
                  </tr>
                      <tr>     
                        <td width="100%"><font size="2" color=302F2F>by @comment.Comment_User...[@comment.Comment_Date.ToShortDateString()] </font></td>
                  </tr>
                }
            </table><hr />      
       </td>
        </tr>        
     }

 }
 </table>
```

I was thinking just using string builder to wrap all this html, is there a more efficient or elegant way to do it?

Comment: That't not HTML - looks like a razor view. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Yes, its razor and it gets rendered as html. I need a html string version of this..In my new function, I just started placing everything in a string using the same structure/for each etc... I need to give the html string to an external source.

Comment: Cant your external source just consume this using an httprequest?

Comment: It doesn't have access to the pages, the reason to send it as html.

Comment: So, you want to render the HTML from these views and send _that_ out?

Comment: If you look at the answers below..they pretty much got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the method I use:

```
public static string RenderPartialToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{

    controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I placed this code in a helper class, I tried calling it from a controller like this:   DocumentUtility.RenderPartialToString(MyApp.Controllers.QuestionController, "QuestionIssues", QuestionIssue);

Comment: its complaining that first argument (controller) is a type, not valid argument. Same thing for my 3rd argument.

Comment: The first argument has to be an **instance** of the controller class, not the class itself. Are you calling it from within a controller? If so, change the first parameter to `this`

Comment: "this" worked..what about the 3rd argument (model)?...also I want to pass an id? Similar to this: Url.Action("Agency", "Question", new { id = agencyId });

Comment: sorry figured out the 3rd, I sent it a list of QuestionIssue.

Comment: @Chaka No problems! Glad I could help :).

Answer (score 0):

If you need that HTML code as a string within another view, you can use `HtmlHelper.Partial()` method since that returns a string value.

If you need that outside of MVC view then you need something much more complex, like described here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String